# Occult Adventures: Does the Navel Chakra Breath Weapon grant a Reflex Save?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The new *[Occult Adventures](http://paizo.com/products/btpy9egu?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Occult-Adventures)* book provides a new ability for people with a Ki Pool and a prerequisite feat: Unlocking Chakras.

One of the Chakras is the Navel, and unlocking it provides access to a temporary breath weapon. It is not described as granting a saving throw of any kind, but it is a breath weapon.

Does it grant one? If so, what is the save DC?

Answer (score 3):

There is no saving throw for the navel chakra power IMO.

The power states,

> the initiate can channel the serpent-fire as a breath attack that deals 2d8 points of damage in a 30-foot cone. This radiant gout of orange-red liquid flame somewhat resembles fire, but bypasses all forms of energy resistance, protection, and immunity.

One could argue that this counts as a breath weapon and therefore is subject to the [normal breath weapon rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Breath-Weapon-Su-), which state:

> Some creatures can exhale a cone, line, or cloud of energy or other magical effects. A breath weapon attack usually deals damage and is often based on some type of energy. Breath weapons allow a Reflex save for half damage (DC 10 + 1/2 breathing creature's racial HD + breathing creature's Con modifier; the exact DC is given in the creature's descriptive text). A creature is immune to its own breath weapon unless otherwise noted. Some breath weapons allow a Fortitude save or a Will save instead of a Reflex save. Each breath weapon also includes notes on how often it can be used, even if this number is limited in times per day.

But a) it doesn't really say "breath weapon" in the chakra power description, just "breath attack" which is close but not legal-text close, b) the breath weapon ability says the type and DC of save will be noted and it's not, c) other chakra powers (brow for example) *do* explicitly note there is a save and provide a DC, and d) the "bypasses everything" description of the power makes me think the intent is for full damage.

Comment: I appreciate that you contrasted the listing for breath weapons with the other chakra powers. I haven't gotten around to reading about the chakras in Occult Adventures (though I should, they sound fun), and I'm sure I would have had this same question. +1